# Remove White background on ASP.Net submenu

Tags: asp.net, background

I'm creating a navigation menu and I'm (1) struggling to remove the white background that appears when the submenu is selected. I have searched high and low and I have tried created and adding the a class with z-index = 1000 to a dynamic menu style as well as simply setting the background to transparent. The gradient you see behind the submenu is desired but all of the whitespace is not. Also, I want the entire menu to drop down directly under the department heading. Please help me if possible. I've been searching for a solution for days and I have visited several other sites. If possible I want this solved programatically using CSS or an attribute of an ASP.NET control.

Reference:
Using .Net 4
Language = VB
Software: Visual Studio Professional

Image of the issue:
http://i1332.photobucket.com/albums/w601/OfficialMsRae/Menu_zps7051ce8a.png

This is my ASP.Net Code:

```
<asp:Content ID="Content4" ContentPlaceHolderID="NavigationContentPlaceHolder" runat="server">
<form runat="server">
<div id="NavBarDiv">
    <asp:Menu runat="server" 
        CssClass="NavBar"
        DataSourceID="SiteMapDataSource"  
        MaximumDynamicDisplayLevels="4" 
        StaticEnableDefaultPopOutImage="false" 
        staticdisplaylevels="1"
        staticsubmenuindent="10" 
        target="_blank" 
        Font-Names="Calibri"  
        EnableViewState="false" 
        IncludeStyleBlock="false" 
        Orientation="Horizontal"
        BorderStyle="Solid"
        Borderwidth="1px">
        <LevelMenuItemStyles>
            <asp:MenuItemStyle CssClass="level1"/>
            <asp:MenuItemStyle CssClass="level2"/>
            <asp:MenuItemStyle CssClass="level3"/>
        </LevelMenuItemStyles>
        <StaticHoverStyle BackColor="Transparent" />

        <%--             <StaticSelectedStyle BackColor="White" BorderColor="Gray" BorderWidth="2px" />
        <StaticSelectedStyle BackColor="Black" />
        <StaticMenuItemStyle HorizontalPadding="5px" VerticalPadding="2px" />
        <DynamicHoverStyle BorderStyle="Double" BorderWidth="2px" BorderColor="Gray" />
        <DynamicMenuStyle BackColor="none" />
        <DynamicSelectedStyle BackColor="#000000" BorderStyle="Double" />

        <StaticHoverStyle BackColor="#000000" ForeColor="White" />--%>


    </asp:Menu>
    <asp:SiteMapDataSource ID="SiteMapDataSource" ShowStartingNode="false" runat="server" />
</div>
```

Here is a link to my Stylesheet:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/rx8dr05gf6psxvm/Styles.css

Any help is appreciated. Let me know if i need to provide more information.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the reason this is happening is because the background gradient is only covering the width of the text. For example:

```
|[AR Dashboard]  |
|[AR Performance]|
```

AR Performance is longer and makes the box bigger. What you need to do is give each menu item (AR Dashborad and AR Performance a fixed width, for example:

```
.menuItem {
    width: 100px;
    backgroundcolor: yourgradient;
}
```

After that, they should look like you want:

```
|[AR Dashboard]||||
|[AR Performance]||
```